# When click on the button in a web page of asp.net page(C#) it load again and the jquery function that supposed to work didn't work properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, button, pageload

I am looking for something that will help me to do some jquery stuff. 
I have a button  when it is clicked it supposed to show a dialog and deactivate the screen for the time dialog box is on screen. It is working fine with the simple html page. But the problem is occurred in the when form loading event like below 
  
my button is between these tags and when I clicked page refreshed and I can see that dialog box for second like ghost in while page is refreshing. I just want stop this page loading when the button click and to jQuery code run . Hopefully I explain clearly.this is the jQuery code.

```
 $("#showDialog").click(function () {
    $(".page-header").block({
              message: '<h1>Processing</h1>',
              css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the event from bubbling by using preventDefault()

```
    $("#showDialog").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $(".page-header").block({
            message: '<h1>Processing</h1>',
            css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
        });


});  //<---This seemed to be missing in your code.
```